# AJAX callback not added using form_alter

Tags: ajax, forms

I want to perform a AJAX callback to check the value of a custom field during user registration. Because the form is already built, I need to use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

1. But, no callback is added using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Maybe it is overwritten later on? Therefore, I tried `$form['#after_build']`.
2. But that fails too for the AJAX property. Adding another form element works perfectly fine.

The code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function member_id_check_v2_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  switch ($form_id){
    case 'user_register_form':
    case 'user_profile_form':
      $form['#after_build'][] = '_member_id_check_v2_ajax';
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function _member_id_check_v2_ajax($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['member_id_check_v2_callback_wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("The default value will be changed"),
  );

  $form['custom_field']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => '_member_id_check_v2_callback',
    'wrapper' =>  'member_id_check_v2_callback_wrapper',
  );

  return $form;
}

function _member_id_check_v2_callback() {
    watchdog(WATCHDOG_DEBUG,'Callback worked!');
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the AJAX callback on `#process` callback as `#after_build` callback is too late to inject AJAX.

Check out the this [link](http://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/how-add-ajax-validation-specific-field-node-form) and the example code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function kf_link_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ('example_node_form' == $form_id) {
    //$form['field_link'][$language]['#after_build'][] = '_kf_link_field_link_after_build';
    $form['field_link'][$language][0]['#process'] = array('link_field_process', '_kf_link_field_link_process');
  }
}

/**
 * Custom form api process function
 */
function _kf_link_field_link_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $element['url']['#description'] = '<div id="example-link"></div>';
  $element['url']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'kf_link_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'example-link',
  );
  return $element;
}

/**
 * Custom ajax callback function
 */
function kf_link_ajax_callback(&$form, $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  $field_link = $values['field_link'];
  $language = $values['language'];
  $url = $field_link[$language][0]['url'];
  $duplicate_nodes = _kf_link_get_url_nid($url);
  foreach ($duplicate_nodes as $duplicate_node) {
    if (isset($duplicate_node->nid) && ($duplicate_node->nid != $values['nid'])) {
      drupal_set_message(t('This URL already exists in <a href="!url">!title</a>', array('!title' => $duplicate_node->title, '!url' => "node/{$duplicate_node->nid}")), 'error');
    }
  }
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_html(NULL, theme('status_messages'));
  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => $commands,
  );
}
```